# How to have no Xamarin.ios spash and no display

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

This Xamarin.ios app on iPhone must have no splash and no display whatsoever and must leave previous app displayed.

Is is launched by an Objective-C app and it only runs for a short time and then ends itself, leaving screen of the ObjC app always displayed

I need the app that launched it to remain in focus.

USAGE STEPS...

1. I open the ObjC app, which has command buttons
2. I press button that starts my Xamarin.ios app which should have no display at all
3. ObjC app button menu remains displayed
4. Xamarin.ios app runs and then ends itself
5. ObjC app button menu remains

Please help -- am under the "time gun" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible on iOS - if it makes it easier for you you could have whole the time in this world (and not being under the "time gun") and could not solve it unless Apple changes something in future iOS releases which is unlikely.

The closest you could get to it is to record the screenshot of ObjC app before it launches Xamarin.iOS app, send it some way to Xamarin app (the best way would be if they could be the same App Group), put empty splash screen and ensure that it displays just a split of the second and then display your screenshot in the Xamarin app and do whatever you want to do.

Comment: Also, will not go through Apple store -- is for in-house use only and is temporary work-around.

Comment: @DougNull if you don’t have jailbroken phone, it is probably still not possible. If you have it then it is likely possible but it is illegal and I don’t have experience in that.